# Hair and head for MTG Chandra Ablaze

Tags: design

Is there any female head and hair that can approximate the picture from the MTG card "Chandra, Ablaze"?

[image]

I don't even have to have the goggles, I'm just looking for that "crazy psycho chic" look.

Comment: Perhaps Ghost Rider? "Minifigure, Head, Modified Alien with Trans-Orange Flaming Hair and Skull with Yellow Eyes Pattern" <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26990pb02>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer by RSchulz has a much better "hair" than I was able to find, but I did find a couple encouraging heads by searching for "angry face". **Edit:** Since the hair RSchulz found is not detachable from the head, I added hair at the end of the post.

They look like they're meant to be inside hoods/helmets so some modification (color matching, removing edge lines) may be necessary depending on how realistic or close-up you want to go.

[image]

[Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Balaclava with Face Hole, Orange Eyebrows, Cheek Lines, Smile / Angry Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1098&name=Minifigure,%20Head%20Dual%20Sided%20Balaclava%20with%20Face%20Hole,%20Orange%20Eyebrows,%20Cheek%20Lines,%20Smile%20/%20Angry%20Pattern%20-%20Hollow%20Stud#T=C&C=5)

[image]

[Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Balaclava with Light Nougat Face, Red Eyes, Firm / Angry with Gritted Teeth Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb2044&name=Minifigure,%20Head%20Dual%20Sided%20Balaclava%20with%20Light%20Nougat%20Face,%20Red%20Eyes,%20Firm%20/%20Angry%20with%20Gritted%20Teeth%20Pattern%20-%20Hollow%20Stud)

And the best hair I can find is this one:

[image]

[Minifigure, Hair Ponytail High with Orange Flame Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=190004)

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to find any standalone trans-orange flaming hair pieces, which really limits the flexibility of any design. The best I found was the head suggested by RSchulz. Note that this part does come in a number of [colors and prints](https://rebrickable.com/search/?show_printed=on&include_accessory=1&include_gear=1&q=26990&search_type=all). Another possible option might be the [Firestorm version](https://rebrickable.com/parts/26990c01pr0003/minifig-head-special-with-trans-orange-flames-and-reddish-brown-face-and-gold-headband-print-firestorm/):

[image: Firestorm's head]

Another option that doesn't look as much like fire but that gives more flexibility for selecting an appropriate face may be [Syndrome's hair](https://rebrickable.com/parts/24787/minifig-hair-spiked-tallest-in-center/):

[image: Syndrome's hair]

Answer (score 3):

Nobody has posted anything better, so I'll try it as an answer:

Perhaps Ghost Rider?  [Minifigure, Head, Modified Alien with Trans-Orange Flaming Hair and Skull with Yellow Eyes Pattern](http://bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26990pb02)

[image: Ghost Rider head]

Comment: Is the flaming hair fused onto the minifig head, or is a separate, removable piece?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's fused. I like the idea of Syndrome's hair!